# SOAP API: Not able to pull cod_fee column {Magento 1.9}

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

I am trying to pull `cod_fee` column value from `sales_flat_invoice` or `sales_flat_order` table from SOAP API.

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('https://www.mysoresareeudyog.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
$sessionId = $proxy->login('api-user', 'api-key'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary

$result = $proxy->salesOrderInfo($sessionId, 'ORDL000000012124');
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($result);
```

However, the above code is not fetching the table column `cod_fee`. I have gone through many articles. Still I am not able to resolve this. This is the 1st time I am working on API.

> Edited

`wsdl.xml` file (included in -> salesOrderEntity)

```
<element name="base_cod_fee" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
```

`wsi.xml` file (included in -> salesOrderEntity)

```
<xsd:element name="base_cod_fee" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
```

---

`Api.php` file

---

```
public function info($orderIncrementId)
{
    $order = $this->_initOrder($orderIncrementId);

    if ($order->getGiftMessageId() > 0) {
        $order->setGiftMessage(
            Mage::getSingleton('giftmessage/message')->load($order->getGiftMessageId())->getMessage()
        );
    }

    $result = $this->_getAttributes($order, 'order');

    $result['shipping_address'] = $this->_getAttributes($order->getShippingAddress(), 'order_address');
    $result['billing_address']  = $this->_getAttributes($order->getBillingAddress(), 'order_address');
    $result['base_cod_fee']  = $this->_getAttributes($order->getBaseCodFee(), 'base_cod_fee');
    $result['items'] = array();

    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->getGiftMessageId() > 0) {
            $item->setGiftMessage(
                Mage::getSingleton('giftmessage/message')->load($item->getGiftMessageId())->getMessage()
            );
        }

        $result['items'][] = $this->_getAttributes($item, 'order_item');
    }

    $result['payment'] = $this->_getAttributes($order->getPayment(), 'order_payment');

    $result['status_history'] = array();

    foreach ($order->getAllStatusHistory() as $history) {
        $result['status_history'][] = $this->_getAttributes($history, 'order_status_history');
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: by default that field is not there see [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.info.html)

Comment: You need to customize api to get that column

Comment: @MineshPatel Yes, exactly!! How do I fetch this column? Because this is also a part of the invoice. Till now I have customised the module of the Magento. I don't know how to customise API. Not even basics can you explain me a bit.

Comment: app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/wsdl.xml
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/wsi.xml

add your column in complexType  salesOrderEntity and include in response from file

app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Api.php method info()

Comment: @MineshPatel I made the changes as you said. Still I am not able to pull cod_fee

Comment: paste you code here

Comment: make sure you have  cleared cache after changes

Comment: @MineshPatel I have pasted my code. Also I have cleared all the cache

Comment: have you added base_cod_fee after billing_address in xml ?

Comment: protected function _getAttributes($object, $type, array $attributes = null) this is the function definition

Comment: simply put like this $result['base_cod_fee']  = $order->getBaseCodFee();

Comment: @MineshPatel I made the changes as you said. 1) Added base_cod_fee just after billing_address in xml. Also `$result['base_cod_fee'] = $order->getBaseCodFee();` and cleared the cache also.

Comment: is is working or not ?

Comment: are you getting field base_cod_fee in response  ?

Comment: no, it is not working

Comment: are you getting field base_cod_fee in response as key ? or not OR not getting value in it ?

Comment: this is the api url https://www.mysoresareeudyog.com/todo.php I am not getting here

Comment: all seems good check for [soap cache issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303488/in-php-how-can-you-clear-a-wsdl-cache)

Comment: converting comments to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default that field is not there see [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.info.html)

You need to customize api to get that column

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/wsdl.xml 

app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/wsi.xml
```

add your column in complexType salesOrderEntity and include in response from file

`app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Api.php` method

> info()

Disable SOAP WSDL cache. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303488/in-php-how-can-you-clear-a-wsdl-cache#answer-303514)